# How to write about Arrived Function with C# on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When Character is arrived destination, I want to get callback.

However I don't want to write into Update Function.
If I've get to write into Update, I want to write smartly and elegant code.

when we make game, if there is design pattern.

Let me teach about it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Vector3 targetPosition;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private bool arrived;
    private Transform myPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        myPosition = GetComponent<Transform>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.updateRotation = false;
        agent.updateUpAxis = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(targetPosition);
    }
    
    public void MoveTo(Vector3 position, float stopDistance, Action onArrivedAtPosition)
    {
        targetPosition = position;
        // here!
        if (arrived)
        {
            onArrivedAtPosition();
        }
    }

    private void IsArrived()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(myPosition.position, agent.destination) < 1.0f)
        {
            arrived = true;
        }
        arrived = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did not do much unity lately - but why would you need all this? You do not do any increamental position changes until you reach the destination - you simply set it.  You never call `MoveTo()` - you never call `IsArrived()`` ...

Comment: Thanks you for your comment.
The reason why i want to this code.
I watched this youtube video and the video said about this code.
I want to write Gather code like RTS.

https://youtu.be/__tU3_tmgKA?t=116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Coroutines are like small temporary Update routines but easier to control and maintain.

```
private Coroutine _currentRoutine;

private bool IsArrived()
{
    // Instead of setting a field directly return the value
    return Vector3.Distance(myPosition.position, agent.destination) < 1.0f;
}

public void MoveTo(Vector3 position, float stopDistance, Action onArrivedAtPosition)
{
    // Here can/have to decide
    // Either Option A
    // do not allow a new move call if there is already one running
    if(_currentRoutine != null) return;
    // OR Option B
    // interrupt the current routine and start a new one
    if(_currentRoutine != null) StopCoroutine (_currentRoutine);

    // Set the destination directly
    agent.SetDestination(position);
    
    // and start a new routine
    _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine (WaitUntilArivedPosition(position, onArrivedAtPosition));
}

private IEnumerator WaitUntilArivedPosition (Vector3 position)
{
    // yield return tells Unity "pause the routine here,
    // render this frame and continue from here in the next frame"
    // WaitWhile does what the name suggests
    // waits until the given condition is true
    yield return new WaitUntil (IsArrived);

    _currentRoutine = null;
    onArrivedAtPosition?.Invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a script like the one bellow and attach it to an empty gameobject, then place that empty gameobject at target position. Make sure your IsArrived method (in Unit script) is public and also assign the unit on the empty gameobjec's TargetPoint script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TargetPoint : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float radius = 1f;
    public Unit unit = null;
    private bool called = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        SphereCollider c = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
        c.radius = radius;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, radius);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (called)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(other.transform == unit.transform)
        {
            unit.IsArrived();
            called = true;
        }
    }

}
```